# how many 'text' column a table could have in mysql? I have this error "Row size too large (> 8126)."

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a application which is kinda complex to explain how it works. But this is the situation I'm in,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIELD1 (TEXT) FIELD2(TEXT) FIELD3(TEXT) .........................FIELD70(TEXT)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**POSSIBLE DATA SIZE FOR A SINGLE FIELD: around *500 characters*.**

I have around 20 tables in a single database like this.

I know it's too bad idea to have this much column in a single table. But I have to go with this since It's went too far and can not modify number of columns.

**Now I got some error like,** 
"Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline."

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

- I altered the table as **ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED**. = didn't work out
- I altered the table as **ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC**.    = didn't work out
- **innodb_file_format = Barracuda**                = didn't work out
- I altered the column to **VARCHAR(500)**          = didn't work out

What could be the actual error? I've seen plenty of the answers for this problem bur they are telling these above methods that I've tried and failed.

Comment: Can you provide a full `CREATE TABLE`? Also these two documentation-pages may help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html and this question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806725/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te)