# phpMyAdmin - Unexpected behaviour of mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Two versions of phpMyAdmin have been installed on 2 different Windows PCs at nearly the same date.
phpMyAdmin indicates that the versions of phpMyAdmin, of the mySQL server and of the Apache web server are strictly identical in all the details that phpMyAdmin provides.
**However, both installations do not work the same as regards import of SQL files** : one suffers from a "erreur #1118 - Row size too large" syndrom for some files, while the other does not (thus jeopardizing an independant validation process for the DB evolution ...).
I've been unable to identify any clue so far : all .ini files are identical, and the error (ER_TOO_BIG_ROWSIZE) seems to be raised in the eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x...\bin\perror.exe file, which I don't know how to ivestigate.
I doubt that the difference of Windows OS level might have a possible impact.
Would anybody have a fair suggestion ?

Comment: Is `phpMyAdmin` not a tool which can be installed on a webserver ?  So how do you have two installed versions ?

Comment: Thats's right : on 2 PCs, with same versions of Apache server an of phpMyAdmin. The goal is to replicate the same installation on two distinct machines, for concurrent validation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (>65535)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885572/error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-65535)

Comment: Based on the error (most of the times part of the sql statment is in the error message) you should be able to find the sql statement that is causing the error. Copy that statement, and compare the two installed systems on the behavior is this single statement, this will finding the cause of this problem more easy.