# NotSerializableException for java.util.Optional with Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to save an entity using JPA but getting `NotSerializableException` for a field of type Optional.
Here my goal is to store custom object (here it is of type `Grade`) in JSON serialized form.

[Student.java]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String name;

    @Lob
    private Grade grade;

    public Student() {
    }
```

[Grade.java]

```
public class Grade implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7351334541533041431L;
    private Optional<Integer> marks;

    public Optional<Integer> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(Optional<Integer> marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Grade [marks=" + marks + "]";
    }

}
```

[StudentRepository.java]

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    public Student findByName(String name);
}
```

[StudentRepositoryTest.java]

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class StudentRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByName_thenReturnEmployee() {

        // given
        Student alex = new Student("alex");
        Grade grade = new Grade();
        grade.setMarks(Optional.ofNullable(90));
        alex.setGrade(grade);

        entityManager.persist(alex);
        entityManager.flush();

        // when
        Student found = studentRepository.findByName(alex.getName());

        System.out.println(found);
        // then
        assertThat(found.getName()).isEqualTo(alex.getName());
    }
}
```

After running above test getting following exception for `marks` field in `Grade` class:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.Optional
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:115)
    ... 49 more
```

I have included following dependency to support java8 data types for Jackson:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Spring boot version: 2.1.6.RELEASE

Shared the same code at: https://github.com/Omkar-Shetkar/spring-repo-test

What could be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Optional` is not `Serializable`. JPA attempts to serialize non-text (anything but `String`, `char[]` or `Char[]`) fields marked with `@Lob`.

The recommended approach would be using a JPA converter to serialize the object into a Json while persisting and deserialize the persisted Json on reads. Jackson supports serializing Optional fields, you just have to add `jackson-datatype-jdk8` dependency and register `Jdk8Module` on your `ObjectMapper`. 
A `GradeConverter` implementation looks like this:

```
@Converter
public class GradeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Grade, String> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public GradeConverter() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Grade grade) {

        if (grade == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(grade);
    }

    @Override
    public Grade convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {

        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return objectMapper.readValue(s, Grade.class);
    }
}
```

And on your `Grade` field:

```
@Convert(converter = GradeConverter.class)
private Grade grade;
```

If you insist on serializing the field (I mean Java serialization), you should provide custom serialization methods.
You could read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290777/java-custom-serialization).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Hibernate tries to serialize your Grade object and since it uses the default serialization algorithm, it tries to serialize the `Optional<Integer> marks` field.

Now, in Java Optional is not serializable: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

So the serialization fails.

Since Optional is not intended to be used in data fields (see [this discussion] for reasons[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)), consider removing an optional, leaving `Integer marks`)

Comment: Actually my goal is to store custom object in an entity in JSON serialized form into the table. A custom object contains other fields apart from Optional also. 
It seems hibernate is using Java serialization to store the object. Can I use jackson provided JSON serialization instead ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Hibernate/JPA, but this seems to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738569/how-to-map-a-map-json-column-to-java-object-with-jpa

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is completely irrelevant here; when you're saying that you want to use `Serializable`, you're talking about *Java serialization*, and for whatever reason `Optional` isn't `Serializable`.

The recommended approach for "optional" properties like this in persistent entities is to store the actual value as a nullable field and translate in the getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

The **com.google.common.base** also have the Optional class which is **serializable**:

[Java Doc](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)

[Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava)

Comment: While link can lead to useful information, it's good to describe solution a little more.

Comment: just need to add [dependency] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava and change the import package from **java optional** to **guava optional**.