# how to map json field with jpa or hibernate in pojo?

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, jpa

I am using MySQL and jpa/hibernate.
So I want column as Json datatype in JPA, but its not supporting.
Also therefore I am not able to use in criterion query.
Which is appropriate ways to handle this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738569/how-to-map-a-map-json-column-to-java-object-with-jpa

Answer (score 0):

This is something that worked for me

```
@Entity
@Table
@TypeDef(
    name = "jsonb",
    typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class Blah{

 //add your fields

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String jsonField;

 //add your getters and setters

}
```