# JPA group by query

Tags: java, jpa, java-8, spring-data, grouping

I have a table EMPLOYEES

| EMP_ID | DEPT_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FSJFJF |
| 2 | 1 | GRFGFF |
| 3 | 2 | SFFKSF |
| 4 | 2 | DFSFSF |

I want to create a map of EmployeeDTO by grouping employee data based on deptId.

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

    private Integer deptId;

    private List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

Currently I am using

```
SELECT a FROM Employee a
```

and using groupingBy

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> map = employees.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(employee -> employee.getDeptId()));
```

But it is inefficient for a very large data as it using in memory grouping instead of using database group by query. Do I need to use Projections here? Any examples? Please help.

Comment: Your suggested DTO should in fact be what the employee entity should look like.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Employee entity will have 3 fields - id, deptId and employeeName. I just want to segregate them based on deptId in different groups.

Comment: You should start by trying to write the raw SQL query you need, then go from there in your JPA code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using MySQL.

MySQL has [`JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg), [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object)

Then your query will look like following

```sql
SELECT dept_id,
json_arrayagg(JSON_OBJECT('name', name, 'emp_id', empId)) as employees
from EMPLOYEE group by dept;
```

It will return following result set

```
dept_id employees

1       [{"name": "FSJFJF", "emp_id": 1}, {"name": "GRFGFF", "emp_id": 1}]
2       [{"name": "SFFKSF", "emp_id": 3}, {"name": "DFSFSF", "emp_id": 4}]
```

Now how do we map this result into JPA.

**JpaConverterJson.java**

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class JpaConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

  private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object meta) {
    try {
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(meta);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
      return null;
      // or throw an error
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    try {
      return objectMapper.readValue(dbData, Object.class);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      // logger.error("Unexpected IOEx decoding json from database: " + dbData);
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

**DepartmentWiseEmployees.java**

```java
class DepartmentWiseEmployees {

    private Long deptId;

    @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    // omitting getter and setter
}
```

Then a simple JPQL inside the Repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JPARepository<Employee, Long> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT dept_id, json_arrayagg(JSON_OBJECT('name', name, 'emp_id', empId)) as employees from EMPLOYEE group by dept;", native = true)
    public List<DepartmentWiseEmployees> findDepartmentWiseEmployees();
}
```

Reference:

- [How to map a map JSON column to Java Object with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547965/2143128)