# Spring JPA and JSON/JSONB Postgres column

Tags: json, postgresql, jpa

I've seen some questions related to this same topic, but I cannot seem to find one that can simply answer the basic question.

I'm relying on JPA CRUD Repository to save an entity. I have a Postgres DB table with a column of type JSON. I have the related JPA Entity with the corresponding column annotated with `columnDefinition = "JSON"`

When trying to save an entity to this table, I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "..." is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 201
```

Any ideas of what's going on?
Thanks!

I tried to use JSON data type column in a postgres table using Spring JPA, but I keep getting  `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738569/how-to-map-a-map-json-column-to-java-object-with-jpa

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use jsonb because that is more flexible and performs better than the json data type but you can  use the Hibernate-specific @Type annotation to specify the type. This instructs Hibernate to handle the JSON column appropriately.

```
    @Type(type = "json") // Use Hibernate-specific @Type annotation
    private String jsonColumn;
```