# How can we solve this type of database error with xammp server 3.3.2 version

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter-2

I have an issue with my database: while I am updating my form I got this error:

```
Error Number: 1118
Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

In `codeignator2` I think the data is heavy but I keep changed some settings in `my.ini` but I am getting same error.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te

Comment: ya buddy i changed  but its  not changed as i change the setting before i post question but nothing changes i getting this type of error. innodb_buffer_pool_size =  32M @Cyclonecode
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 800M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_file_format = Barracuda

Comment: And you restarted the mysql server after updating the settings?

Comment: yes buddyy but still i getting this type of error @Cyclonecode

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by changing the columns’ datatype to `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.