# MySQL ERROR 1118 Row size too large, changed VARCHARS to TEXT but still getting the error

Tags: mysql

I have a very "wide" MySQL table, with nearly 700 columns.  (I inherited this system and will be moving to a key-value store in the future, but that's outside the point of this question.)  When trying to add a `VARCHAR(500)` I was met with this error:

> `ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs`

After [a little research I decided to turn the eight `VARCHAR(2000)` columns in the table into `TEXT` columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506920/713874).  After doing that, and trying to add my new `VARCHAR(500)` again I was met with the same error.

Now, those `VARCHAR(2000)` columns probably didn't have 500 characters between them, but they did have more than the ~20 characters I was trying to insert into the new `VARCHAR(500)` field.

As I understand it, `VARCHAR` only takes up as much space as it *needs*.  But if a table can only hold 8126 characters then either it should never have been able to allocate eight `VARCHAR(2000)` since 8 x 2000 = 16,000 which is much more than 8126, or an error would happen when you tried to *fill* those fields beyond 8126, regardless of what data you put where.  **So my first question is: is that correct that a table could accept eight `VARCHAR(2000)` but you would run out of space while filling them?**

**And my second question is: why didn't moving those `VARCHAR(2000)` to `TEXT` clear up space for me to add a new `VARCHAR(500)`?**  Especially since I was only putting ~20 characters in that 500 and there were about 100 characters across the 2000s already.

NOTE: I do see in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/) ways to increase the table size, but I'm not trying to do that.  This is a question about theory, not looking for a work-around solution.

Comment: Once you altered the table, did you OPTIMIZE it?

Comment: Just tried it: `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead` then `OK`, but same error (`Row size too large`) when trying to add the `VARCHAR(500)`.