# How to use PySpark to stream data into MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am currently working on a single page web app that allows users to upload large CSV files (currently testing a ~7GB file) to a flask server and then stream that dataset to a database. The upload takes about a minute and the file gets fully saved to a temporary file on the flask server. Now I need to be able to stream this file and store it into a database. I did some research and found that PySpark is great for streaming data and I am choosing MySQL as the database to stream the CSV data into (but I am open to other dbs and streaming methods). I am a junior dev and new to PySpark so I'm not sure how to go about this. The Spark [streaming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) says that data must ingested through a source like Kafka, Flume, TCP socets, etc so I am wondering if I have to use any of those methods to get my CSV file into Spark. However, I came across this [great example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-connect-to-sql-database) where they are streaming csv data into Azure SQL database and it looks like they are just reading the file directly using Spark without needing to ingest it through a streaming source like Kafka, etc. The only thing that confuses me with that example is that they are using a HDInsight Spark cluster to stream data into the db and I'm not sure how to incorporate that all with a flask server. I appologize for the lack of code but currently I just have a flask server file with one route doing the file upload. Any examples, tutorials, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the streaming part but spark can handle large files efficiently - and storing to a db table will be done in parallel, so without much knowledge about your details, and provided that you have the uploaded file on your server, I'd say that:

If I wanted to save a big structured file like a csv in a table, I would start like this:

```
# start with some basic spark configuration, e.g. we want the timezone to be UTC 
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
# this is important: you need to have the mysql connector jar for the right mysql version:
conf.set('jars', 'path to mysql connector jar you can download from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/')
# instantiate a spark session: the first time it will take a few seconds
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .appName('Huge File uploader') \
    .getOrCreate()

# read the file first as a dataframe
df = spark.read.csv('path to 7GB/ huge csv file')

# optionally, add a filename column
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('filename', F.lit('thecurrentfilename'))

# write it to the table
df.write.format('jdbc').options(
            url='e.g. localhost:port',
            driver='com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',  # the driver for MySQL
            dbtable='the table name to save to',
            user='user',
            password='secret',
        ).mode('append').save()
```

Note the mode 'append' here: the catch in this is that spark cannot perform updates on a table, it is either append the new rows or replace what is in the table.

So, if your csv is like this:

```
id, name, address....
```

You will end up with a table with the same fields.

This is the most basic example I could think of so that you start with spark, with no considerations about a spark cluster or anything else related. I would suggest you take this for a spin and figure out if this suits your needs :)

Also, keep in mind that this might take a few seconds or more depending on your data, where the database is located, your machine and your database load, so it might be a good idea to keep things asynchronous with your api, again I don't know about any of your other details.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! @mkaran
I gave it a shot but it gives me an error at the last step on `df.write()` method saying ```Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.```

Comment: It looks like it is a MySQL error. I was using MySQL version 8.0 and tried everything suggested [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te/44274003) and on other posts and I also restarted my computer and MySQL server several times but nothing worked. I also downgraded to MySQL verison 5.7 but I was still getting the same error.

Comment: I cannot seem to write into my MySQL database so my only other option would be to use another db that pyspark can connect to.

Comment: Hi @Mario, can you please tell me what the output of `print(len(df.columns))` and `print(df.count())` is after the read.csv?