# AWS RDS: MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run a CREATE TABLE with 234 columns and I'm getting a `MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126)` error.

Ideally I wouldn't have such a table but I do and rewriting the code so that one isn't needed is not practical.

According to [MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22637733/569976) setting `innodb_strict_mode` to `0` will do the trick but idk how to do that. When I click on the parameter group for this DB and do a search for `innodb_strict_mode` nothing comes up.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can `ALTER TABLE` to switch from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innodb_strict_mode is settable in the DB cluster parameter group as opposed to the Parameter group. And you can't set it - or any parameter - in the Default parameter group - you have to create a new parameter group.

Once you set it you'll need to reboot each of the instances in the cluster.